# OAuth 2.0 in background while creating events on GCAL from Salesforce using Google Calendar API v3 (REST API)

Tags: triggers, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, apex-code, gcal

My Situation:
I'm trying to populate a shared Google Calendar when an event is created on the Salesforce interface. Im currently using the latest Google Calendar v3 (RESTful) API for the same https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/ with APEX my development language.

I'm using a trigger that catches all the value from the fields (trigger.new) and passing those values to a class that does the JSON serialization, authentication and API call.

Till now, I was able to get all the data from the object and pass is to the class and get it serialized. But I need to do the OAuth 2.0 call before I can make a Google Calendar API call. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

I have setup my application on the Google API Console and obtained the Client ID, Client Secret etc.

The usual way OAuth 2.0 works is that an authentication page pops-up waiting for the user to grant access to the API so that it can access the calendars linked to the users account.

My question:
Is there any way I can get the OAuth done in the background using a static/private key which is either obtained by granting access just once but not every time or just programmatically using the key value in the class to authenticate the user.

Looking forward to getting useful suggestions/inputs/help from everyone.

Comment: Using this toolkit as a base,http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_Apex_JSON

Answer (score 0):

If the user --once-- have made the authorization you got the access_code and the refresh_code.
I found it helpful to store both codes with the application (here Firefox and password manager). With the next start of the application (Firefox/extension) I use the refresh_code to request a new access_code. That is used during the session for any further calendar call.